# Run pgAdmin4 on a custom path with Docker

Tags: docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have a pgAdmin4 running within a Docker Container.

I'm trying to run on a custom path because there is another server running on the default `/` path.

I've tried all possible env vars but as soon as pgAdmin runs, it redirects to `/` and the page goes to the other server running.

```yaml
pgadmin:
    restart: always
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.10
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=someemail
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=somepassword
      - PGADMIN_DISABLE_POSTFIX=true
      #- PGADMIN_ENABLE_TLS=false
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
      - PROXY_X_FOR_COUNT=2
      - PROXY_X_PROTO_COUNT=2
      - PROXY_X_HOST_COUNT=2
      - PROXY_X_PORT_COUNT=2
      - PROXY_X_PREFIX_COUNT=2
    
    networks:
      - databases
      - nginx
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true" 
      - "traefik.backend=pgadmin4" 
      - "traefik.frontend.priority=600" 
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Method:GET" 
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/url-secreta/pgadmin"
```

I want the pgAdmin4 to respond on `www.mywebsite.com/url-secreta/pgadmin`.

I've already defined the routes on my Kong gateway, but when the request reaches pgadmin it redirects to `/`.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accroding to [Container Deployment — pgAdmin 4 6.10 documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.10/container_deployment.html#traefik)

> The SCRIPT_NAME environment variable has been set to tell the container it is being hosted under a subdirectory (in the same way as the X-Script-Name header is used with Nginx), and a label has been added to tell Traefik to route requests under the subdirectory to this container.

you should add `SCRIPT_NAME` to your `environment`

```yaml
pgadmin:
    restart: always
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.10
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=someemail
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=somepassword
      - PGADMIN_DISABLE_POSTFIX=true
      #- PGADMIN_ENABLE_TLS=false
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
      - PROXY_X_FOR_COUNT=2
      - PROXY_X_PROTO_COUNT=2
      - PROXY_X_HOST_COUNT=2
      - PROXY_X_PORT_COUNT=2
      - PROXY_X_PREFIX_COUNT=2
      - SCRIPT_NAME=/url-secreta/pgadmin # add this line
    
    networks:
      - databases
      - nginx
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true" 
      - "traefik.backend=pgadmin4" 
      - "traefik.frontend.priority=600" 
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Method:GET" 
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/url-secreta/pgadmin"
```

Comment: do you know about mount volumes? i want to mount volumes to be able to dump data from database

Comment: Do you means dump data from PostgreSQL Container? Maybe I will use `docker exec` to get into the container then dump data via `pg_dump` command. Finally, copy file from docker to host via `docker cp`. You don't need to mount volumes to dump data.

Comment: pgadmin has a option to select the table, database, or query result i want to export and generate a csv or other fortmat from it... this file will be stored into the container, i'm not sure which folder... i just wanted to have a easy way to get this data

Comment: try `- ./storage:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage`

Comment: I just test on my machine, the default path of dump file is in `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage`

Comment: @RafaelLima there will be a tooltips after click restore button. It shows the location of the dump file.